# Tensorflow getting stuck on prediction when deploying with gunicorn

Tags: python, tensorflow, gunicorn, tensorflow2.0

I've built myself a flask web server, and am deploying it with Gunicorn. It works perfectly well with the default flask app.run(), but this isn't meant for production, so up until now I've had my flask app running on gunicorn.

However, since adding my TensorFlow program to my site, when I go to run a prediction it runs forever, I have timeout set to like 5 minutes. I tested with a print statement before and a print statement after my predict. Second print never shows up.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running heavy calculations inside the route, you better change your program design.

At your route start the job on some other thread or process and return the status of the process start and ID to query its progress.

Then you call query with polling [or web sockets] your heavy task with your ID, and return its status till the process is done and you can return the results

Comment: It run super quick outside gunicorn. Its not a super heavy calculation, its something to do with gunicorn I think. On some of my other routes where i was running heavy computations, i switched to doing it with websockets like you said. I might run tf.js in the browser and do it with websockets as an alternative.